# How to share symfony2 session across subdomains

Tags: php, session, symfony, multi-tenant

How can I share the session across subdomains symfony2? I am using Symfony version 2.0.14

I have mysite.com when user logs in to this site and move to corporate.mysite.com it should show logged in as its the same application and all the resources are shared same config files etc. just created a virtual host which points to same project folders.

A bit of googling shows this soln

```
framework:
    session:
        domain: .mysite.com
```

but this does not work for me. Can somebody guide me to the right direction?

-deepak

Comment: It seems this was fixed in 2.1 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3423

Comment: This discussion might be helpfull https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/N3mG27ervwg

Comment: In newer versions of symfony (at the time or writing 2.7) it should be: `cookie_domain: .mysite.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check If you have a valid tld in your local environment

Comment: Thanks Ankit. As you suggested I checked my local setup which was mysite.dev which dint work for me, and it works fine with mysite.com

Comment: Nice catch. I also wasn't using a valid `TLD` domain.